# Titanium - uisegmentedcontrol

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to do something in titanium that is similar to the iphone uisegmentedcontrol

I'm currently using buttons in arrays but it's not an efficient method if there needs to be position shifting. Because position shifting would require me to go to each button to shift them.

So there's a huge problem with alignment.

Is there a way to implement uisegmentcontrol in titanium? Google doesn't give me anything related to titanium.

Comment: Use Titanium.UI.ButtonBar or Titanium.UI.iOS.TabbedBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TabbedBar` for this purpose.

```
var segment = Titanium.UI.iOS.createTabbedBar({
    labels:['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    backgroundColor:'#336699',
    top:50,
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BAR,
    height:25,
    width:200
});
myWindow.add(segment);
```

Please check these links for more options:

1. [TabbedBar](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.TabbedBar)
2. [ButtonBar](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ButtonBar)